# How do I get emacs to use tabs for indentation in PHP mode?

Tags: php, emacs, tabs

I added these lines to my .emacs file

```
(require 'php-mode)
(setq php-mode-force-pear t)
(add-hook 'php-mode-user-hook
      '(lambda ()
         (setq indent-tabs-mode t)
         (setq tab-width 4)
         (setq c-basic-indent 4)))
```

Which mostly works but what when I indent under another line that's indented it uses spaces for the indentation.  I'd like it to use tabs for the indentation.  Emacs will align properly but uses spaces for the alignment instead of tabs.

If I add the line

```
(global-set-key (kbd "TAB") 'self-insert-command)
```

I get tabs to my heart's content but then I lose the nice indentation ability (which is what I'm trying to avoid).  For personal projects I use spaces for indentation generally but I'm working with other devs who prefer tabs at the moment and having a hell of a time getting this right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm dubious that `php-mode-user-hook` is used. The php-mode I use certainly doesn't refer to it, and it's a pretty non-standard name, AFAIK.

Try changing that to `php-mode-hook`

edit: Also, where did you get `c-basic-indent` from? That should be `c-basic-offset`

Comment: That seemed to do the trick.  Thanks.  I got the php-mode-user-hook from googling somewhere.  The c-basic-indent was probably a mistype.